# Arcmap Field Calculator Python sPrefix

Tags: python, prefix, arcmap

I am working in Arcmap using the Field Calculator.

I have a attibute with values like the follwoing:

> "addr:city"="Bielefeld","addrostcode"="33699","addr:street"="Westerkamp"
>   "addr:city"="Bielefeld","addr:street"="Detmolder Straße"
>   "addr:city"="Bielefeld","addr:housenumber"="34"

I want to extract them into individual attributes.

So I thought I need codes like:

> dim city
>
> if sPrefix = "addr:city":
>       return everything past "addr:city" until a comma appears

Any ideas how to solve that. I don't have much experience unfortunatley.

Thanks,

Uli!

here is a screenshot

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtXCI.png)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at python's [csv](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module.

**Edit:**

I've never used Arcmap, but I'd imagine you can still import modules in it.
If the strings are pretty regular, you could just parse the data without it though:

eg.

```
#test.py

def func(s, srch):
    parts = dict([item.replace('"','').split('=') for item in s.split(',')])
    return parts.get(srch,'')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tags = '"addr:city"="Bielefeld","addrostcode"="33699","addr:street"="Westerkamp"'
    print func(tags, 'addr:city')

>python test.py
>Bielefeld
```

Comment: I don't think it is possible to use the csv module in ArcGIS field calculator.

Answer (score 0):

something like this, define your own function:

```
In [40]: def func(x,item):
    spl=strs.split(",")
    for y in spl:
        if item in y:
            return y.split("=")[-1].strip('"')

   ....:         
   ....:         

In [53]: strs='"addr:city"="Bielefeld","addrostcode"="33699","addr:street"="Westerkamp"'

In [54]: func(strs,"addr:city")
Out[54]: 'Bielefeld'

In [55]: func(strs,"addr:street")
Out[55]: 'Westerkamp'
```

Comment: I will give this a try. Could you exmplain what x and y stands for?

Comment: x is the variable that points to the `strs` passed and y is another variable name used in for-loop.

Comment: Unfortunatley I don't have much experience. I don't get it to work.

Comment: @user1738154 can you post what you were trying to do in the question body.

Comment: I added a screenshot. Please have a look at it. Thanks!

Comment: what is tags? pass the string instead to `func()` : `'"addr:city"="Bielefeld","addrostcode"="33699","addr:street"="Westerkamp" '`

Comment: "tags" is the name of the column where all the values are. "test" is the column where the result of the calculation shall be stored.

Answer (score 0):

As I read your question, you want to extract a string which looks like `'"addr:city"="Bielefeld","addr:housenumber"="34"'` into individual (key, value) pairs.  The easiest way to do this is probably to use the csv reader (http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html).  You will need to determine exactly how to use it in your use case, but here is a generic example which is likely to work:

```
import csv
for pairs in csv.reader(attribute_list):
    key, value = pair.split('"="')
    print key, value
```

Comment: I don't think it is possible to use the csv module in ArcGIS field calculator. Thanks for the hint though!

Comment: You don't mention the field calculator in your question - perhaps you should state it...

Comment: I thought having it in the title is enough.

Comment: Yes, sorry - don't know how I missed that!